# Calculating in Polish notation

Tags: c++, stack, notation

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include “stack.h”
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char *a = argv[1]; 
   int N = strlen(a);
   stack<int> polish(N); int el;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      if (a[i] == '+'){
         el = polish.readStack(); polish.outofStack();
         polish.inStack( el + polish.readStack()); polish.outofStack()
      }
      if (a[i] == '*'){
         el = polish.readStack(); polish.outofStack();
         polish.inStack(el * polish.readStack()); polish.outofStack()
      }
      if ((a[i] >= '0') && (a[i] <= '9')){
         el = polish.readStack(); polish.outofStack()
         polish.inStack(10 * el + (a[i++]-'0'));
      }
   }
   cout << polish.outofStack() << endl;
}
```

How does it work? And what does it mean this line?

```
polish.inStack(10 * el + (a[i++]-'0'));
```

Comment: Such a strange implementation of `stack`. It is a well-known practice to call methods `push` and `pop` but not `readStack` and `inStack`. Also, `pop` should automatically remove the last element without calling `outOfStack`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this shouldn't be working: The result of the operations us pushed into the stack (without removing the second operand) and then discarded?!

Comment: `polish.inStack(10 * el + (a[i++]-'0'));` if you assume `stack<int>::readStack()` returns an `int` this would mean you pass 10 * the result of that call + the next character that was given as input to `stack<int>::inStack();`

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Looks like a standard interface with non-standard names - `inStack` is `push`, `readStack` is `top`, `outOfStack` is `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is an algorithm which reads and calculates [**Reverse (postfix) Polish notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

For example,

```
1 2 3 + 4 - -
```

means

```
Add 1; add 2; add 3; sum up the last two; add 4; substract the last two; substract the last two.
```

i.e.

```
1 - ((2 + 3) - 4) = 0
```

This code line:

```
polish.inStack(10 * el + (a[i++]-'0'));
```

is supposed to combine a number by appending digits.
`(a[i++]-'0')` is converting from char digit like '3' to integer 3.

Initially, we have a zero in our stack.
For example, if you have "123", it will read them char by char this way:

1. read `1`. Get the last number from stack (0), make `0 * 10 + 1` = 1. Push it back to stack
2. read `2`. Get the last number from stack (1), make `1 * 10 + 2` = 12. Push it back
3. read `3`. Get the last number from stack (12), make `12 * 10 + 3` = 123. Push it back.
4. Great! 123 number has been read.

However, this code sample is a bunch of bad practices.

1. It is a well-known practice to name stack functions `Pop` and `Push`, but not `readStack()` and `inStack()`.
2. Stack structure requires element to be removed after reading. `readStack()` does not provide it.
3. Several `if`s instead of `switch` statement.
4. Never increase your counter within the loop.
5. This code actually does not work because it does not split values.

Comment: There's often also `peek `, which is doing what `readStack` seems to be doing.